# Adding Dependency to Android Studio

Tags: android, maven, dependencies

Can anyone help me how to add [this library](https://github.com/sannies/mp4parser) to my android studio project.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.googlecode.mp4parser</groupId>
    <artifactId>isoparser</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.5.4</version>
  </dependency>
```

Comment: please try to answer the question, if you know, instead of down voting it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

this is how you add it in android studio:
in your build.gradle (Module: app) add this to your dependencies:

```
 compile 'com.googlecode.mp4parser:isoparser:1.0.5.4'
```

it should look like this:

```
dependencies{
  //other dependencies
  compile 'com.googlecode.mp4parser:isoparser:1.0.5.4'
}
```

I hope this helps :)

Comment: this gives me error failed to resolve compile 'com.googlecode.mp4parser:isoparser:1.0.5.4' can you help me out ?